# Remove all except one colour from an image (commandline or code)

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I would like to extract a single colour (e.g. #a87830) from an image, changing every other colour to white. The input can be a bit noisy, so *adjacent* pixels of a close colour could be included. Ideally all non-white pixels at the end would be converted to black (i.e. output is a 1-bit-depth image).

I might want to batch process this, so I am hoping for something like an imagemagick commandline, or something I could code up using the PHP imagemagick extension. (I am sure ImageMagick must be able to do this, if the right parameters can just be worked out, which is why I tagged it, but I am open to other software, as long as it works on Linux.)

**Background:** I am trying to do the first preprocessing stage for the [ContourTrace](http://oorienteering.sourceforge.net/?page_id=2) program, which is nicely shown by this image:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one to try:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK259.png \
 -fuzz 33%                           \
 -fill black                         \
 -opaque "#A87830"                   \
 -threshold 12%                      \
  black+white.png
```

The `-fuzz` parameter makes all colors match that are within a certain proximity of the color defined by `-opaque`. No `-fuzz`, and you'll match these pixels only which are exactly `"#A87830"`.

The `-threshold` converts color pixels to black or white, where the percentage defines the limit: above turns black, below turns white.

[image: black+white.png]

You can modify the command from `-opaque "<color-definition>"` to  `+opaque "<color-definition>"` to ***invert*** the meaning of the color selection: it will replace pixels that are NOT this color (this time I skip the `-threshold` parameter in order to keep colors):

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK259.png \
 -fuzz 33%                           \
 -fill black                         \
 +opaque "#FFFFFF"                   \
  other.png
```

[image: other.png]

Comment: Aha! Changing from `-opaque` to `+opaque` gives almost what I want (black and white are the wrong way round, but I think even my ImageMagick skillz can sort that one out...)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is sophisticated enough for you. Convert all pixels similar, within 30% of your stated colour, to black and then make the rest white.

```
convert in.png -fuzz 30% -fill black -opaque "#a87830" -threshold 10% out.png
```

[image]

You can *"add in"* more tones that you would like to become black by adding further `-opaque` commands, like this

```
convert in.jpg -fuzz 20% -fill black  \
    -opaque "#a87830"                 \
    -opaque "#a6725f"                 \
    -threshold 1% out.png
```

which may allow you to decrease the `fuzz` and thereby remove other tones you don't want.

Comment: Thanks! What are the different meanings of the 30% and 10% in your commandline? I was hoping there would be something with the meaning of "allow a similar colour but only if adjacent to a pixel of the target colour". That would allow for jpeg/scanner fuzziness, but not include the black and purple lines that your example has.

Comment: The 30% means *"select pixels within 30% in terms of colour distance"* from your value of `a87830`. The threshold at 10%, means set all pixels with RGB vakues less than 25,25,25 (i.e. 10% of 255) to black and all those above that value to white. So the output image will be pure black and white.

Comment: I notice that even if I reduce both fuzz and threshold to 1% I still get all the black lines from the original. (Only the brown lines should be kept, so black lines should go to white just like everything else.)

Comment: ... changing to use `+opaque "#a87830"` and then `-negate` after `-threshold` works nicely. Fuzz of 1% and 5% appear equally good, but 10% included other map features. (Only tested on one map image, so far: it may that it was cleaner than is typical...)